# How to use laravel fortify for authentication in multiple places on the same website

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, laravel-8

When using **laravel/UI** we can create authentication scaffold on multiple places or for multiple users like *admin*, *normal users* by copy-pasting the same scaffold generated by the &*--auth* flag.

How can we achieve the same with Fortify?

How can we use Fortify to authorize admin and normal users?

Answer (score 1):

See the link below. You need to use config function.
https://max-eckel.dev/posts/multi-guard-authentication-with-laravel-fortify

Answer (score 0):

In order to do multiauth, we have to use multiple guards.
But laravel fortify only supports one guard (as of sep-2022) in the **config/fortify.php file**.
So what we need to do:

1. We need to use authenticateUsing method and return our specific authenticating model (User/Admin/whatever) in the **boot** method of **FortifyServicePorvider**:

   ```
   Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
   // check based on the type request:
   switch($request->type){
       case'employee':
           // return employee model all the checks;
       break;

       case 'admin':
           // return admin model after all the checks;
       break;
   }
   });
   ```
2. Check the same request parameter in the **register** method of **FortifyServicePorvider** and set the guard (make sure to create a guard in the config/auth.php file) to use, using global config help:

   ```
   switch($request->type){
   case'employee':
       config(['fortify.guard' => 'employee']);
       break;

   case 'admin':
       config(['fortify.guard' => 'admin']);
       break;
   }
   ```